# C/C++ how to run the same switch case till its condition is true and continue with out crashing?

Tags: c, console

in c console windows i cant get this application to check each check consistent, so like instead of the if "while" like in java then it changes and as long as the condition doesnt match it loops over and over again till you break out

how can i do that in c?

```
 case 1: //add
        printf(OPENWINDOW);
        printf("\t\tAdd A Reminder  (enter the number)\n\n\n\n");
        printf("for which day?   \n\n");
        int tempday;
        scanf("%i", &tempday);
        if ( tempday >= 32){
            printf("sorry we dont go that high on days.. try again!\n");
            scanf("%i", &tempday);}
        printf("and which month my king?   \n\n");
        int tempmonth;
        scanf("%i", &tempmonth);
        if ( tempmonth > 12 ) {
            printf("sorry we dont go that high on month... try again!\n");
            scanf("%i", &tempmonth);}
        printf("what year?\n\n");
        int tempyear;
        scanf("%i", &tempyear);
        while ( tempyear < 2012 || tempyear > 2020 ){
            printf("Wow that is an incorrect year and you know it, try again\n");
            scanf("%i", tempyear);
            printf("What do you want to call this reminder?");
//            scanf("%c", char titletemp[]);

            }

        break;
        case 2: // view
        printf(OPENWINDOW);
```

Comment: Look closely at the contents of the while loop. This is why `cin` is good (unless that C++ tag was a complete accident and you really only meant to tag it with C).

Comment: what is cin? that while was a mistake im trying to keep this conditions running till true then move to the next check know what i mean?

Comment: `cin` is what you should be using instead of `scanf` in C++, which you've tagged your question with. The problem lies with the input.

Comment: my bad i seen people relate c++ with c for syntax alikness that is why i said "in c" thanks tho now i know

Comment: Maybe instead of `if ( tempday >= 32) {`, you meant `while (tempday >= 32) {`?

Comment: I've removed the C++ tag, as it's not relevant here.

Comment: thanks that worked :) sorry newbie @VaughnCato

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While in C works just like while does in Java. You wrap a section of code with while, and whatever is inside it gets run until the condition is false.

However, your `scanf` is wrong:

```
scanf("%i", tempyear);
```

It should be:

```
scanf("%i", &tempyear);
            ^
```

Note the `&`, which means "pass the address of this variable".

Comment: oh man how many times am i going to slap my face on this typos, my bad ill fix it and update